# MySQL exclude query by WHERE

Tags: mysql

How can I get all `picture` values and exclude rows with `nofoto.jpg`
Something like that:

```
SELECT `picture` FROM `members` WHERE `picture` != `nofoto.jpg`
```

Comment: Try and see what it gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the backtigs arround the values by single qoutes:

```
SELECT `picture` FROM `members` WHERE `picture` != 'nofoto.jpg'
```